# A subspace of Lie algebra which in not a subalgebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am a newcomer for the course of Lie algebra. A subalgebra of a Lie algebra is subspace with the same Lie product.

> Can we have a subspace of a Lie algebra which is not a subalgebra
> ?

Comment: A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the Lie bracket is the cross product) should do the job.

Comment: "A subalgebra of a Lie algebra is a subalgebra having the induced product" is not the correct definition. It's not a definition at all, actually.

Comment: Since no-one has said it explicitly, the correct definition of a Lie subalgebra is a subspace that is **closed** under the Lie bracket. That is $[x,y] \in V$ for each $x,y \in V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$ with basis $\{x,y,z\}$ and Lie brackets
$$
|x,y]=z,\; [z,x]=y,\; [y,z]=x. 
$$
Now consider the subspace $V$ spanned by $x$ and $y$ of dimension $2$. It is not a Lie subalgebra, since $[x,y]\not\in V$.

In fact, $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$ has *no $2$-dimensional subalgebra* at all. This is often an argument to show that it cannot be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$, which certainly has $2$-dimensional subalgebras.

Comment: You are saying that $so_3$ has no subalgebra of dimension $2$? Is this correct?

Comment: @PriyaPandey, see [$2$-dimensional Lie groups of $SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2198401/721644)